# use d-k i see only usb0

Tags: usb

I have 2 usb devices plus the sd card.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        6276224 4636916   1297448  79% /
devtmpfs          469544       0    469544   0% /dev
tmpfs             473880       0    473880   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             473880    6468    467412   2% /run
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             473880       0    473880   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        1953184  466784   1486400  24% /media/usb0
/dev/mmcblk0p5     64366   20438     43928  32% /boot
tmpfs              94780       4     94776   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p3     27633    1568     23772   7% /media/pi/SETTINGS
```

Also, are my devices mounted automatically?
When I use the `mount` command it states all are already mounted?

Comment: Have you tried accessing their contents?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have one mounted partition on a USB `/dev/sda1`. There is also a mounted partition on your SD `/dev/mmcblk0p3`.

The `findmnt` command might give a clearer view of what is mounted.

You ask "are my devices mounted automatically?". If you boot to GUI it will normally automatically mount inserted devices, but this depends on `/etc/fstab` settings which can override the default.